# How to set property values based on a condition in ANT?

Tags: junit, ant

I want to create a condition in my ant build.xml file where if I set the `domainName` property is set to `Stage`, then set the `appbox1URL` property value to `http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx1` and set the appbox2URL to `http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

However when I run the build.xml file, it does not set the appbox url values. AM I doing something wrong?

```
<property name="appbox1URL" value=""/>
<property name="appbox2URL" value=""/>


<condition property="appbox1URL" value="http://10.xxxx.xxx.xxx" property="appbox2URL" value="http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx">
<equals arg1="${domainName}" arg2="zzz"/>
</condition>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) task but you can only set one property per condition (rather than two, as you are trying to set in your OP).

So, split the assignments into two `condition` instructions:

```
<condition property="appbox1URL" value="http://10.202.111.111">
    <equals arg1="${domainName}" arg2="Stage"/>
</condition>

<condition property="appbox2URL" value="http://10.202.111.112">
    <equals arg1="${domainName}" arg2="Stage"/>
</condition>
```

Comment: It displays blank values for both appbox when I open up the file front end after running it wih stage being the domain name

Comment: Actually I think thats the problem, I think the condition works but I don't see it output in the report because I am saying in an xml file which gets converted to a html report to brab the value of appbox1 and 2 urls based on the value of their property by selecting the xml document. But technically before this script is run, the appbox1 and 2 values will be defaulted to having no values, it's only after the conditions then it passes through values